# How to use 'EXISTS' in this context and send email with this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to SQL and am trying to set up a query that will only show me the top row of the results.  I'd like to set the resulting query to a variable called, 'inspectionYear' and check if 'YEAR(InspectDate)' equals 1753.  If it does, I'd like to send an email with the results of the query.

However, I get a couple of errors when trying to set this up.  The first error is referring to a subquery and looks like I need to use EXISTS.  The other errors I'm less clear on.  Here is the error message:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 33 Only one expression can be
> specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
> EXISTS. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 35 Invalid column name 'x'.
> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 38 Could not find stored procedure
> 'sp_send_dbmail'.

```
DECLARE @inspectionYear INT
SET @inspectionYear ='x'
SET @inspectionYear = (SELECT TOP 1 *
                       FROM Inspect
                       INNER JOIN Well ON Inspect.WellKey = Well.PKey
                       WHERE YEAR(InspectDate) < 1950
                       ORDER BY InspectDate)
SELECT @inspectionYear -- Returns NULL

IF x = 1753
    USE msdb
    GO
    EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='OilGasEmail',
    @recipients='test@test.email',
    @subject='Hello world',
    @body= 'This is a test, fear not.'
```

Comment: The subquery should only return 1 column.

Comment: TOP 1, but no ORDER BY? Doesn't it matter which value you get?

Comment: You have declared `@InspectionYear` as an `int` but then given it a default value of `'x'` which isn't an `int`. You'll need to change that.

Comment: Then you have `IF x = `. Should this really be `IF @InspectionYear =`?

Comment: You write "equals 1753." but your code does not check that, does it? If you don't know exactly what the logic should be, you will struggle to write code to implement it. In addition, "GO" is not a tsql statement and has a special purpose. Here you don't appear to need it as you can use the MS supplied email procedures regardless of the current database for your connection. Lastly, merely indenting code does not make it a block for an IF statement. You must use BEGIN/END pairs for that purpose.

Comment: @SteveLovell so delete the line saying "SET inspectionYear = 'x'"?

Comment: @SteveLovell Yes, I'd like to have `IF @InspectionYear = 1753`.  After looking at another tutorial online I thought I had to set `InspectionYear` to a variable first.

Comment: `IF (SELECT MIN(YEAR(InspectDate)) FROM ...) = 1753`

Comment: You can't have `GO` in the middle of a procedure, it's just a batch separator, and will end the procedure there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @inspectionYear INT
SET @InspectionYear = (SELECT TOP 1 YEAR(InspectDate)
                       FROM Inspect
                       INNER JOIN Well ON Inspect.WellKey = Well.PKey
                       WHERE YEAR(InspectDate) < 1950
                       ORDER BY InspectDate)
SELECT @inspectionYear -- Is this fixed? Remove this line if it returns the expected value

IF @InspectionYear = 1753
BEGIN
--Email Code here
END
```

If you need content from your query in your email, the following approach can be taken:

```
DECLARE @InspectionYear INT
DECLARE @AFieldFromWellTable varchar(20) -- Do similar for each field you're interested in
DECLARE @AFieldFromInspectTable varchar(20) -- Check the data types, I made these up

SELECT TOP 1
    @InspectionYear = YEAR(InspectDate),
    @AFieldFromWellTable = Well.AFieldFromWellTable,
    @AFieldFromInspectTable = Inspect.AFieldFromInspectTable
FROM
    Inspect
    INNER JOIN Well ON Inspect.WellKey = Well.PKey
WHERE
    YEAR(InspectDate) < 1950
ORDER BY
    InspectDate
```

You will now have multiple variables populated, which you can use to build your email text. And of course you can check the `@InspectionYear` variable as before in order to send the email only on the condition that the minimum year found is 1753.

Comment: What do you mean by, "-- Is this fixed?"?  I wanted to have the variable @inspectionYear be a year so that I can check if it equals 1753.  If it does, I'd like an email of the first row from the query.

Comment: heres what I have so far:
`DECLARE @inspectionYear INT
SET @inspectionYear = (SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Inspect
INNER JOIN Well ON Inspect.WellKey = Well.PKey
WHERE YEAR(InspectDate) < 1950
ORDER BY InspectDate)
SELECT @inspectionYear

IF @inspectionYear = 1753
 BEGIN
  USE msdb
  EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='OilGasEmail',
  @recipients='test@test.email',
  @subject='Hello world',
  @body= 'This is a test, fear not.'
 END`

I get error:
"Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Comment: The `is this fixed?` is just my own comment. You can probably remove the entire line. I'm just asking whether this now returns the expected value rather than `null` as you'd given.

Comment: The requirement to include content from the subquery into the email really changes things. You'll notice that in my code I've not used `SELECT *`. You can't combine the `SET` with the `SELECT *`, you need to set the value to a single thing, not to a data row.

Comment: I don't absolutely need the top row of the results in the email.  A simple message saying "a result was found" would be fine.  When I run your first code suggestion I get the error "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS".

Comment: Are you still using `SELECT TOP 1 *`? If so, you need to change that as indicated. That `SELECT` needs to be returning one and only one field. That's what the error message means.

Comment: I had `SELECT TOP 1 *`.  Once I changed it to `SELECT TOP 1 YEAR(InspectDate)` I was able to produce a table with one column and row showing the item I was searching for.  The email is also working.  Thanks for your help!  I'm glad to have a working example I can use for the future.